# Anchor tag name searchinh using regular expression

Tags: regex, c#-2.0

I have this anchor tag standard

```
      <a href = "\code.ixc">temp_file</a>
```

There could be 10 files listed this way. Now I want to search "temp_file" string.   I used

```
      <a href=\".*\">(?<name>.*)</a>
```

but it returning me 0 count for pattern searched. Can anybody help me with correct regular expression to search this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href\s=\s".*">(.*)<\/a>` could be a starting point. You missed the spaces around the `=` and forward slashes have to be escaped. `"` on the other hand, usually doesn't have to be escaped (excpet you're using it in an programming environment where you put the regex into a string.
The `(.*)` could be possibly be replaced with `(\w)`.